# Maven build fails to deploy in jenkins websphere deployment plugin

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am doing a maven build in my jenkins and creating a war file, I have configured the websphere deployer plugin and tested the connection successfully. I am trying to deploy the war file to webshere deployer plugin but I am getting an error

> Error deploying to IBM WebSphere Application Server: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern.

I guess it is expecting an ant build while I am deploying maven build.

I had copied the required jar files for websphere deployer plugin in jenkins. Also I have included the certificates to cacerts. All the configurations look good to me. Can any one help me in figuring out what could be the issue.

Here is my websphere configuration:

```
Deployment Target : "WebSphere:cell=DESKTOP-DUHNNUFNode01Cell,node=DESKTOP-DUHNNUFNode01,server=server1"

Generated EAR level : Java 8 

Generated Context : /


Client Keystore File Path   
C:\Jenkins files\DummyClientKeyFile.jks
Help for feature: Client Keystore File Path
    Client Keystore Password    
•••••
Help for feature: Client Keystore Password
    Client Truststore File Path 
C:\Jenkins files\DummyClientTrustFile.jks
Help for feature: Client Truststore File Path
    Client Truststore Password  
•••••
```

The ear file should be deployed successfully but I am getting the following error:

> Connecting to IBM WebSphere Application Server...
>   Error deploying to IBM WebSphere Application Server: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw 'C:\CMrest2\CMRestAPI-master\CMRestAPI\target**/*.war'. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html for syntax
>   Cannot rollback to previous version: artifact is null
>   Build step 'Deploy To IBM WebSphere Application Server' changed build result to FAILURE
>   Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins deploy plugin can't find the war file since following path isn't a relative path to your workspace:

C:\CMrest2\CMRestAPI-master\CMRestAPI\target**/*.war

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I tried changing the slash and also giving the actual war file name but i am getting the same error. I am not sure why it looks for ant GLOB pattern in maven build.

Comment: Probably plugin just use it as dependency to match the files. Btw, did you try giving relative path to workspace?

Comment: Yes , this is a relative path issue . Jenkins is looking for the war file within the workspace rather looking at the absolute path . I copied the war file to the jenkins workspace and deployment was successful . So we need a work around to place the war file into workspace after the maven build is done .